# How to stop astropy printing dtypes when writing a fits file with a table?

Tags: python, astropy

I have this test code called table.py :

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
counts = np.array([312, 334, 308, 317])
names = np.array(['NGC1', 'NGC2', 'NGC3', 'NGC4'])
c1 = fits.Column(name='target', format='10A', array=names)
c2 = fits.Column(name='counts', format='J', unit='DN', array=counts)
coldefs = fits.ColDefs([c1, c2])
tblHdu  = fits.TableHDU.from_columns(coldefs)
hdu     = fits.PrimaryHDU(np.random.randn(1000))
hduList = fits.HDUList([hdu])
hduList.append ( tblHdu )
hduList.writeto ( "test.fits", output_verify="ignore", overwrite=True )
```

And it produces an unwanted output like this :

```
python3 table.py 
A10
I11
```

I would like to get rid of those "A10" and "I11" printouts, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporally suppress the standard system output when writing out your FITS file. The following snippet redirects stdout to `/dev/null`, saves `test.fits`, and then restores the output back to `sys.stdout`:

```
import os
import sys 
with open(os.devnull, "w") as stdout_null:
    stdout_sys = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = stdout_null
    hduList.writeto ("test.fits", output_verify="ignore", overwrite=True)
    sys.stdout = stdout_sys
```

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade astropy.

There was an accidental `print()` function introduced on Nov 4, 2016, in commit [aaaa6fb](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/commit/aaaa6fb56fdb09f93b58c13871765e4b9dd6475e#diff-703b4b625a97b7b26058e3e859bfe8d8), which was only removed a year later on Nov 8, 2017, in commit [68050d8](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/commit/68050d88e9fd3512d0194e108c2cd20d194b650d#diff-703b4b625a97b7b26058e3e859bfe8d8).

Version 2.0.4 and 3.0 (current) were released after Nov 8, 2017, and don't have that annoying `print()` output anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Unfortunately, we may not change our version of astropy as we work in large networks that must glue to the same standards, that's the only reason the other answer was choosen.